# CCITT Group3 2D compression algorithm

Tags: python, compression, tiff

I am trying to write a function in python that takes as an input two rows of bits like this:

```
ref= '00011000000000000'
line='11100000111111001'
```

and compress the second based on the first; in other words, I am trying to implement the [CCITT Group3 2D algorithm](http://www.fileformat.info/mirror/egff/ch09_05.htm#CH09-DMYID.1.4).

After reading the specification there a lot of things still unclear for me:

1. Does the a0a1 run has always to be white?
2. Does the implementation differ in TIFF?

I have this picture encoded using CCITT Group3 2D:

[image: small encoded strip]

```
ref= '111111111111111111'
coding_line='111111111100011111'
```

when I extracted the code for the second line it was like this

```
['1', '1', '000010', '1']
```

What I don’t get is the last value '1' which translates to '0'. Why is that last value?

Comment: The TIFF version of G3-2D follows the CCITT standard. Each line starts with white and each change flips the color except for horizontal mode which encodes a black and white run together.

Comment: dose the run from a0 to a1 always white or it can be black ??

Comment: In my decoder, I don't use a variable named a1, but a0 alternates between black and white (it can be both). Each vertical code causes the color to flip.